# How to fix two conditions on one statement

Tags: python-3.x

I want to connect these two lines with an or statement but it keeps looping infinitely, however it works with only one statement attached.

```
SDepth = input('Enter the depth of either 38 or 48: ')

while (SDepth != '38') or (SDepth != '48'):
    SDepth = input('Enter the depth of either 38 or 48: ')
```

Comment: While SDepth not in (‘38’, ‘48’)

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? if 2, `input()` will interpret as an int. check `type(SDepth)`

Comment: If SDepth=38 this is true, if it =48 it is true, so it's always true and you're in an infinite loop. I think you want `while (SDepth != '38') and (SDepth != '48')` or the sytax Aman Garg posted

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're seeing this behavior is because of the logic:

```
while (SDepth != '38') or (SDepth != '48'):
```

So this is saying "while the depth is not '38' or it's not '48'". This is different from saying "while the depth is not '38' *and* it's not '48'". It needs to be **and** instead of **or** because of a simple rule of logic called DeMorgan's laws:

"If not (A or B)" is the same as "If not A and not B", so you have to be careful with which to use, "and" vs. "or" since they make quite a difference computationally.

It's like how the following sentences are equivalent:

- "I'll be disappointed if you don't attend the review session today **or** tomorrow." I'm not asking you to go to both, just one or the other.
- "I'll be disappointed if you don't attend the review session today **and** you don't attend tomorrow."

Which is subtly different from saying the following (equivalent) phrases:

- "I'll be disappointed if you don't attend the review session today **and** tomorrow." I'm asking you to go to both.
- "I'll be disappointed if you don't attend the review session today **or** if you don't attend tomorrow."

So it should be:

```
while (SDepth != '38') and (SDepth != '48'):
```